# Undefined symbol: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to main

Tags: c++, g++, undefined, symbols

Have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Record
{
public:
    static Record* GetInstance(string name);
void printName();
private:
Record(string name);
string name_;
static Record *record;
};

Record::Record(string name)
:name_(name)
{
}

Record*
Record::GetInstance(string name)
{
if(record == NULL) {
    record = new Record(name);
}
return record;
}

void
Record::printName()
{
cout << name_ << endl;
}

int main()
{
Record* record1 = Record::GetInstance("sellers");
record1->printName();
Record* record2 = Record::GetInstance("customers");
record2->printName();   
}
```

I am compiling and linking with:
    g++ -g -c -Wall main.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall main.o -o main

The compilation completes without error(1st command). But the linking is giving this error:

```
Undefined                       first referenced    
 symbol                             in file    
Record::record                      main.o    
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to main    
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Wondering how to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable somewhere, i.e.

```
Record *Record::record;
```

Comment: +1 Somewhere is outside the scope of the class but after class definition.